# Blinking Star-Like object in the sky? What could it be?

Tags: identify-this-object

I was out camping with my family at Crater Lake in Oregon. And I was looking up at the stars for a little while when I noticed a star-like object blink, then disappear. I thought I might have been going crazy for a second because I was watching the sky for a while, but then I noticed it blink again but in a different spot, further down. I was watching for a bit and a few seconds later, it let off another bright blink for about a second in a different spot again, and then disappeared.

It did this for about a solid 5 minutes before completely vanishing and never blinking again in the middle of the sky. I realised this blinking was going in a downward zig-zag pattern, there was no way it was a plane, and no way it was a satellite. I showed my family and they saw it too when it was happening, so it wasn't just me.

The object was almost exactly the same brightness as all the other stars but maybe a bit more bright. I have no idea what to think of this, and the object was as big as all the other stars too, I found it weird though that it lit up, then disappeared for a few seconds to just reappear in a different spot kinda far away over and over again.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit this to break it into paragraphs.  It's easier to read questions like that.

Comment: You say it was not a satellite or a plane. It's not quite clear how you know this. Its also unclear what you mean by "the same brightness as other stars but more bright" since stars have various brightness.  However, it was not and astronomical object.

Comment: @Kyler - I say it was a satellite and it was not zigzagging. High altitude tumblers (blinking) are common: EPG is one if I remember correctly. If you can provide the date, time, time zone, and constellations that it passed through, I can identify it and show that it was moving in a consistent motion. (The zigzagging is a result of the difficulty of connecting "random" flashes together. It happens all the time.)